# The method getActivity() is undefined for the type DataAdapter

Tags: android, fragment, cwac-endless

I'm trying to use the demo provided by cwac... how ever when I have pulled it in to my fragment I am getting the error "**The method getActivity() is undefined for the type DataAdapter**"

I am sure its a context thing so I have tried a number of ways to refer to the data adaptor as well as making sure the right support files are been imported ( ie v4 ).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.commonsware.cwac.endless.EndlessAdapter;
import com.commonsware.cwac.endless.demo.EndlessAdapterCustomTaskFragment;

public class Fragment2 extends ListFragment {

    DataAdapter adapter=null;
    ArrayList<Integer> items=null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dod_events, container, false);

        setRetainInstance(true);

        if (adapter == null) {
          items=new ArrayList<Integer>();

          for (int i=0; i < 25; i++) {
            items.add(i);
          }

          adapter=new DataAdapter(items);
          //adapter = new DataAdapter(getActivity(), items);
          adapter.setRunInBackground(false); // Tell the adapter
                                             // we will handle
                                             // starting the
                                             // background task
        } 

        setListAdapter(adapter);        

        // Do Stuff Here
        return root;
    }

    @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Save some state!
    }
}


class DataAdapter extends EndlessAdapter implements
IItemsReadyListener {
    private RotateAnimation rotate=null;

    DataAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

        super(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getActivity(), R.layout.row,
                android.R.id.text1, list));

        rotate=
                new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                        0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(600);
        rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=
                getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        View child=row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        child.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        child=row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
        child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        child.startAnimation(rotate);

        return(row);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean cacheInBackground() throws Exception {
        new FetchDataTask(this, items.size()).execute();

        return(items.size()<75);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemsReady(ArrayList<Integer> data) {
        items.addAll(data);
        adapter.onDataReady(); // Tell the EndlessAdapter to
        // remove it's pending
        // view and call
        // notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @Override
    protected void appendCachedData() {
    }
}

interface IItemsReadyListener {
    public void onItemsReady(ArrayList<Integer> data);
}

class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Integer>> {
    IItemsReadyListener listener;

    /*
     * The point from where to start counting. In a real
     * life scenario this could be a pagination number
     */
    int startPoint;

    protected FetchDataTask(IItemsReadyListener listener, int startPoint) {
        this.listener=listener;
        this.startPoint=startPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Integer> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<Integer> result=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        SystemClock.sleep(3000); // pretend to do work
        for (int i=startPoint; i < startPoint + 25; i++) {
            result.add(i);
        }

        return(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Integer> result) {
        listener.onItemsReady(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call getActivity() this way

```
Fragment2.getActivity();
```

inside of inner class.

Comment: I've tried that in the past... the error you get is "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getActivity() from the type Fragment"

Comment: now I see, These extra classes You have defined are not inner classes. You closed Fragment2 class just before `class DataAdapter`.

Comment: Correct ....although I did that on purpose thinking the code within the fragment could call it in the same way a class could be if I had imported it I'm guessing this is not best practise ?

Comment: each class should be in separate file named `classname.java`. That is a general rule. Inner classes are used to easier encapsulate complex logic of some outer class and this is specific for this class only. If You need these extra classes to be in outer scope (You used them in other classes) You may pass `Activity` or `Context` in constructor. I don't know Your project details so can't point to specific answer but this is a general rule again.

Comment: Thanks for that Gustek.... I guess one of the reasons I did it this was was to keep relevant code in one place rather than .javas....